# How to calculate the mass-matrix for a Lagrangian with $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$ symmetry?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mass, symmetry, field-theory, group-theory

Consider a Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi_i\partial^\mu\phi_i - V(\phi);\\V(\phi)=-\frac{1}{2}\mu^2\phi_i\phi_i+\frac{1}{4}\lambda\phi_i\phi_i\phi_j\phi_j.$$

I understand that the mass spectrum of the particles in the theory can be obtained by:

$m^2_{ij}=\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial\phi_i\partial\phi_j}|_{\phi=\phi_0}.$

The minimum of the potential is given by:

$\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi_k}= -\mu^2\phi_k+\lambda\phi_k\phi_j\phi_j =0\implies\phi_k=0 $ or $\phi_j\phi_j=\frac{\mu^2}{\lambda}$

Now to obtain the mass spectrum:

$\frac{\partial^2V}{\phi_k\phi_l}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_l}(-\mu^2\phi_k+\lambda\phi_k\phi_j\phi_j)=-\mu^2\delta_{kl}+\lambda\phi_j\phi_j\delta_{kl}+2\lambda\phi_k\phi_l$

Substituting the minimum obtained above:

$\frac{\partial^2V}{\phi_k\phi_l}|_{\phi=\phi_0}=-\mu^2\delta_{kl}+\lambda\delta_{kl} \frac{\mu^2}{\lambda}+2\lambda\frac{\mu^2}{\lambda}=2\mu^2.$

I was expecting to obtain a matrix with the masses of the particles, but I just have one mass. What did I do wrong?

Comment: How did you substitute the last term 2\lambda\phi_k\phi_j, you need a to multiply the substitution by a \delta_kj.

Comment: FWIW, it seems $\phi\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is real, and the Lagrangian has $O(3)$ symmetry, not $SU(2)$ symmetry.

Comment: I was going to ask how to do it for $SU(2)$ as well but I think I understand my mistake and should be able to do it for other Lagrangians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've proven that $\sum_j \phi_j^2=\mu^2/\lambda$, not $\phi_k\phi_l=\mu^2/\lambda$.